# Which organizations are/have been effective at lobbying against invasive airport security?

Tags: airport-security, security, passenger-rights

I've been selected for additional screening the last 5 times I've flown and I'm getting tired of it. Not flying is not an option. I want to donate money and time to a larger group that can represent my interests.

What passenger-rights organizations have been or are effective at lobbying against additional screening procedures or invasive screening procedures?

Comment: I would say the evidence points to no group having much luck with that issue, as your own experience seems to show.

Comment: If this is the USA, I think it's possible to ask in writing if you're on a watchlist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good starting point is maybe EPIC (Electronic Privacy Information Center). [They filed a lawsuit](http://epic.org/privacy/body_scanners/epic_v_dhs_suspension_of_body.html) against the usage of body scanners. And they have a ton of other [useful information](http://epic.org/privacy/airtravel/backscatter/). In [this news report](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2010/11/12/invasive-airport-screening-stirs-backlash-airline-passengers/) it is also mentioned that EPIC is very active in this field.

Another interesting group is maybe Electronic Frontier Foundation (EFF). [On their website](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/11/stand-against-tsa-invasive-security-procedures), they list some information how you can complain about the use of body scanners.

Comment: Good answer. Waiting for more to see what else comes up. EPIC and EFF and the ACLU are the front runners in most civil rights cases. I think that EPIC and EFF would have international reach and influence. The disadvantage to these organizations for this question, is that they are broad organizations. There are tradeoffs between these groups and a small focused passenger-rights group.

Comment: http://professional-troublemaker.com/ appears to be filing suits. He seems effective but sometimes a bad suit that loses is worse than a good suit that never gets filed.